# Angularjs : Update a variable after some time

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to show some text while getting data from the server.
I'm trying to update the variable to show loading messages after some fixed time. But I'm unable to do.

```
<div class="circularProgress" ng-if="showCircularProgress" id="circularProgress">
  <md-progress-circular md-mode="indeterminate" md-diameter="70"></md-progress-circular>
  <span>{{progressMessage}}</span>
</div>

  angular.forEach(messageArray, function(msg, i) {
    setTimeout(updateProgressMessage(msg), 1000);
  });

var updateProgressMessage = function(message){
                $scope.progressMessage=message;
            }
```

Could anyone suggest me in setting delay?

Comment: what are you trying to do ?

Comment: please add more context.. what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Use `$interval` and keep your `angular.forEach` inside $interval function.

Comment: updateProgressMessage(msg) method is getting called immediately. so it is always showing the last message in the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to use `$timeout` so that angular knows to run a digest after the callback is called. You'll also need to wrap `updateProgressMessage(msg)` in an anonymous function so that it doesn't get called immediately.

```
angular.forEach(messageArray, function(msg, i) {
    $setTimeout(function() { updateProgressMessage(msg); }, 1000);
});
```

If you want to repeatedly call `updateProgressMessage` use `$interval` instead and your callback will be invoked at regular intervals

For further information see the docs for [$interval](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval) and [$timeout](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout)

**Update**

If `messageArray` contains several items e.g. `var messageArray = [1,2,3,4,5]` then the above code will create a timeout for each item that will each fire at roughly the same time after about 1 second.

I'm not sure this is the behaviour you're after and would have thought you'd want something like this.

```
var messageArray = [1,2,3,4,5];

var intervalPromise = null;

intervalPromise = $setInterval(function() {
    if (messageArray.length > 1){
        // remove an item from the messageArray and update the progress message  
        updateProgressMessage(messageArray.shift()); 
    } else {
        // no more update messages
        $interval.cancel(intervalPromise);
    }
}, 1000);

var updateProgressMessage = function(message){
    $scope.progressMessage = message;
};
```

This will create an interval and fire every second (approximately). Once all messages have been processed the interval is cancelled to prevent any further execution.

Comment: problem is updateProgressMessage(msg) method is getting called immediately

Comment: Passing `$timeout` or `$interval`an anonymous function that calls `updateProgressMessage(msg)` will prevent your callback from being run before the time period has elapsed.

Comment: I can get the timeout to work as expected. I think your issue is that a timer is set for each message in your array at virtually the same time. This will cause a delay of approximately 10 seconds before `updateProgressMessage` is called for each item in the message array at roughly the same time

Comment: Yes. I need to call updateProgressMessage after 1000 milliseconds. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, see my updated answer. This will process all messages in `messageArray` leaving a 1 second gap between each until `messageArray` is empty

Answer (score 0):

Use $timeout.

```
angular.forEach(messageArray, function(msg, i) {
    $timeout(function() { updateProgressMessage(msg); }, 1000);
});
```

If you want to use setTimeout only then do $scope.$apply, which is bad practice.

```
angular.forEach(messageArray, function(msg, i) {
    $setTimeout(function() { updateProgressMessage(msg); }, 1000);
   $scope.$apply()
});
```

Comment: problem is updateProgressMessage(msg) method is getting called immediately

Comment: Increase 1000 to 5000 or some other longer period which is suitable for you.  $timeout(function() { updateProgressMessage(msg); }, 5000);

Comment: If I set timeout to 10secs, after 10secs all updateProgressMessage(msg) function getting call immediately https://plnkr.co/edit/dsKiQhAONIVNM0XojUoY?p=preview